# Quiz Show problem

Tags: probability, limits, infinity

In the “quiz show” example in the notes (§1.2.6 but reproduced alsobelow).

**Setting:**$\;$
In a quiz show a random integer $r$ between $1$ and $10$
is generated. Another, independent such random number s will then be generated, but before
that happens, you are invited to guess whether $s$ will be greater than or less than $r$. If you are
correct, then you win s pounds. If you lose (or if $s = r$) then you win nothing.

**Questions:**

1. At what value of $r$ does it change from being correct to bet
   on s being less than $r$ rather than greater?
2. Show that if the range is $1, \dots ,N$ (instead of $1, \dots , 10$) then in
   the limit as $N$ tends to infinity the change happens at about $\frac{N}{k}$
   where $k$ is a constant that you should evaluate

**Attempt:**$\;$
I understand the answer to 1. is $r = 8$; however, I cannot figure out how to deduce $k$ at all.

Comment: How did you get $r=8$ for part (i)?

Comment: The expected value from 1 to 7 is greater than the expected value of 7 to 10. Hence when you bet s is smaller than 8, the expected value is higher for the first time when you bet less than r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to imagine playing $N$ times with the same $r$ and $s$ taking all the values from $1$ to $N$.  You want to choose your bet to win the maximum total.  This gives you the expected win times $N$.  In the case $N=10$, betting larger on $8$ wins $19$ while betting smaller on $8$ wins $28$, so you should bet smaller on $8$.  Betting larger on $7$ wins $27$ while betting smaller on $7$ wins $21$ so you should bet larger on $7$.

For the second part, if you bet smaller on $\frac Nk$ you win $\frac 12 \frac Nk(\frac Nk-1)$ assuming $\frac Nk$ is whole.  If you bet larger you win $\frac 12(N-\frac Nk)(N+\frac Nk+1)$.  We want to set these equal, so 
$$\frac 12 \frac Nk(\frac Nk-1)=\frac 12(N-\frac Nk)(N+\frac Nk+1)
\\ \frac {N^2}{k^2}-\frac Nk=N^2-\frac {N^2}{k^2}+N
\\2\frac {N^2}{k^2}=N^2+N+\frac Nk$$
For large $N$ the terms in $N^2$ will dominate so we can ignore the terms in $N$ and we see $k=\sqrt 2$.  Note that $\frac {10}{\sqrt 2}$ is very close to $7$

Comment: Such an elegant approach, thank you so much!